# qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped, when trying to return a struct

Tags: c, docker, gcc, arm, qemu

I just noticed that I am unable to have a function return a struct.
I am running this on ARM32/debian docker image with threads enabled.

This is the function that gives me the run time error:

```
struct CEC_call des_CEC_call(char * buffy){

    char request        =   buffy[0];   //  fails here
    buffy+=4;

    char obligation     =   buffy[1];
    buffy+=4;

    struct CEC_call ceccall;
    pepcall.request     = request;
    pepcall.obligation  =   obligation;

    return ceccall;

}
```

But if I change the return type to `void`, there is no issue in running:

```
void des_CEC_call(char * buffy){

    char request        =   buffy[0];   //  doesn't fail here
    buffy+=4;

    char obligation     =   buffy[1];
    buffy+=4;

    struct CEC_call ceccall;
    pepcall.request     = request;
    pepcall.obligation  =   obligation; 

}
```

Return works fine as well with any of the standard return types.

Header where the struct is defined is included in the file with the function although it will still crash even if the struct is defined in the same file. Not sure how to proceed with debugging, any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**

More details, based on suggestions from comments:

I have rerun the same program on my mac as well as some other non arm architectures with docker, and it runs without any noticeable issues. Some aspects relating to bit shifting are slightly different as expected but no run time error from the segmentation fault. I tried running it with various optimisation levels, but to no avail.

I have used GDB before so I thought that might provide some insight, sadly I have not been able to get it to work on this container.

I ensured GDB is installed and recompiled the binary with `-0g`.

I ran docker with `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` and `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined`.

Each time I got:

```
warning: Could not trace the inferior process.
Error: 
warning: ptrace: Function not implemented
During startup program exited with code 127.
```

I am able to use GDB with other non-arm, non-32bit docker images without any issues. I think this is enough for another question, as I've spent ages trying to get GDB working with that environment.

I am not sure really how to verify otherwise, but I have printed out the address `buffy` is pointing and the value held by `buffy[0]` in the preceding functions as well as the problematic one.

Without struct return:

```
address of buffy = 0xff58b9ec
buffer[0] = ff
address of buffy = 0xff58b9ec
buffer[0] = ff
address of buffy = 0xff58b9ec
buffer[0] = ff
```

With struct return:

```
address of buffy = 0xff58b9ec
buffer[0] = ff
address of buffy = 0xff58b9ec
buffer[0] = ff
address of buffy = (nil)
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
```

Struct `CEC_call` does not have any other fields.
It could be a buffer overflow somewhere, but there aren't any buffers at least none made by me. I have not used QEMU IIRC or valingrad before, but will look into them in more details. I can not test nateively at the moment as I do not have the access to the intended embedded linux.

Comment: yeah it wouldn't, mistake when pasting.

Comment: Have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger? It should be possible using QEmu IIRC. Perhaps it's the cause of some undefined behavior in other parts of the code? Perhaps you have a buffer overflow somewhere? And considering that your target OS is Debian (i.e. Linux) then you should be able to build your code natively (on and for the host) and use something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check for problems.

Comment: Try to disable optimization and compile the second code again.

Comment: When you replaced the return value with `void`, the compiler might significantly optimize the function by removing the most part of the code inside it, since it became useless. The removed code might include the code that causes the error. Ragarding possible reason of the error, I assume that it might be caused by overflow of the stack (local variables are allocated on the stack too), but it require further research.

Comment: Did you try to disable optimization and run the second code?

Comment: Does `struct CEC_call` contain other fields except for `request` and `obligation`?

Comment: Are you sure that `buffy` has a valid value?

Comment: @АндрійНемченко no dffierece with optimisation, struct has no other fields.

Comment: @thebusybee no, with the struct included buffy's address is empty

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, I'll look into these tools.

Comment: Without knowing how you printed the values, it's all open. If you have aNULL (nil) pointer given to your function, it *has to* crash. I think you have a problem in another part of your program. Please provide a [example].

Answer (score 1):

```
struct CEC_call ceccall;
pepcall.request     = request;
pepcall.obligation  =   obligation;
```

It seems you have mismatch in names of your variables: `ceccall` and `pepcall`, and you return an uninitialized variable `ceccall`.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the header for the file that has got the `struct CEC_call des_CEC_call(char * buffy)` function declaration has not been included in the calling file.

Function called worked fine if it was returning standard types or void, but with custom struct return the array pointer passed in was nullified. This kind of baffled me initially as I didn’t think it would compile due to missing declaration and this segmentation fault only happened on arm32 architecture, I didn't get that crash on OSX.